# JMeter Java web driver sampler

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter

I have the following Java code for a selenium web driver in JMeter:

```
package com.jmeter.test.scripts;

import java.io.File;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

@Test
public class SnapScreenshot
{
    String fileName = UUID.randomUUID.toString();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Apache\\apache-jmeter-5.5\\Drivers\\Chrome\\109\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "C:\\Temp\\driverlog.log");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File destFile = new File("C:\\temp\\screenshots\\" + fileName + ".png");

        try
        {
            FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, destFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't appear to be executing:

1. The logfile is not created
2. Any `System.out.println()` statements I add are not executed
3. I'm also getting this error message: `ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: unknown protocol: data`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I do have the Chrome web driver configured via "jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config" but this doesn't seem to matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) you need to amend your code accordingly:

1. In the [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) specify the path to your chromedriver executable

   [image]
2. Remove ChromeDriver instance initialization and use `WDS.browser` wherever you need to manipulate the browser

   [image]
3. Switch to ["groovy" language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: so i should stop using java code that works and switch to groovy? it's only not working in jmeter

Comment: If you want to use "Java code that works" you need to compile it into .jar and load it in [JUnit Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.html) sampler. In the WebDriver sampler you don't have possibility to use Java, only [Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) or [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/). If you're very comfortable with Java you might want to come up with [your own JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) instead.

Comment: fair enough. is there a way to make it tie into the http request sampler so it can use already created sessions?